# Bash: pip: command not found for an Install

Tags: bash, raspberry-pi, pip

I am trying to install *pip install twilio* onto a raspberry pi for a school project but, I type in the command the it says *bash: pip: command not found.* I have tried to intall many pip packages, but it still won't read that code. Is there something that I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 15):

`pip` is a package manager specific to Python, and is not installed by default on many systems.

So you first need to install `pip`. Assuming you are using raspbian, you need to use the `apt-get` command, which is the general-purpose package manager for Debian-based Linux systems such as raspbian:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

or the Python 2 version:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

then you should be able to install Python packages such as `twilio` using `pip`.

See this archive of the old Raspberry Pi [guide for installing Python packages](https://web.archive.org/web/20201112022951/https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/software/python.md).

Comment: Thanks! the instructions are still good but the link is sadly broken, here is one from the [internet  archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20201112022951/https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/software/python.md) if someone is curious.

Comment: Thanks, have updated the link with the archived version!